# How to update LibPng in an Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, libpng

Today all my games and my friends games received new alert from Google Play:

> Your app is using a version of libpng containing a security vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `libpng` directly — meaning that you added it yourself to your project — then [use a newer one](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127).

If not, then some other library or framework that you added to your project is using `libpng`. Find out which one has it, then see if they have a new version that addresses the issue.