# How migrate android eclipse project to higher version of libpng?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

Recently my android game-app has been rejected because of containing Libpng Vulnerability. the game created from Buildbox, and i don't have the buildbox project files. i just have eclipse project files. the game working fine but when i tried to change new version of libs folder its not working. so how can i solve this issue, and how to upgrade newer version of libpng

this what message that i got from google play

"This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Vulnerability   APK Version(s)
Libpng library
The vulnerabilities were fixed in libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or higher. You can find more information about how resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article. "

Comment: Check this https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127

Comment: Hi that article its just mention " Download the latest version of libpng from the libpng website" and then submit the updated version of app thats all but i don't have any idea where to put downloaded version of libpng files in eclipse project

Comment: Check this https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/15871, i hope you will get your solution

Comment: Hi this ok for cocoas2d project files, but mine build from builbox and i got only eclipse project files, so where to replace  that libpng folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a mac/linux machine, you can run the following command in your app directory to find which or your library is using libpng:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec fgrep libpng {} \; -print
```

Comment: Hi im using mac. please explain bit more about this please thanks

Comment: this what i got from command `prinss-MacBook-Pro:workspace21 Developer$ sudo find . -type f -exec fgrep libpng {} \; -print
Binary file ./com.prinsapps.jetboy/libs/armeabi/libplayer.so matches
./com.prinsapps.jetboy/libs/armeabi/libplayer.so
Binary file ./com.prinsapps.jetboy/libs/armeabi-v7a/libplayer.so matches
./com.prinsapps.jetboy/libs/armeabi-v7a/libplayer.so
Binary file ./com.prinsapps.jetboy/libs/x86/libplayer.so matches
./com.prinsapps.jetboy/libs/x86/libplayer.so
prinss-MacBook-Pro:workspace21 Developer$`

Comment: Update your buildbox 1.3.7

Comment: What if i don't have buildbox file. just have eclipse project files

Comment: You need to integrate directly with your project. But i think that is not working because your project is exported from `buidbox`. Please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427609/how-to-update-libpng-in-an-android-project and if you not get then write your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thinks,I find the libPng use this command

```
sudo find . -type f -exec fgrep libpng {} \; -print
```